# Tomcat: How to override web.xml servlet init-param

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration, war

Imagine a war-file which you can't change. The .war-file's `web.xml` defines servlets with a set of `init-param` elements (*not*: servlet context parameters).

Using **Tomcat 7**, is there a way to **override some of these parameters**?
(beside changing the extracted `web.xml` from the war-file)

Comment: for tomcat's conf/web.xml, You can check this link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/context.html and topic namely Automatic Context Configuration.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir this url does not say anything about servlet init-param. You probably confused them with servlet context parameters.

Answer (score -1):

```
It's called init-parameter for a reason. So, you can't.

But you can change values at runtime, that's no problem.

After reading the init parameters put them as attributes of the ServletContext (ctx.setAttribute("name", value))
Create a small (password-protected) page that lists all attributes of the ServletContext and gives the ability to change them.
```

Comment: Just as a small comment: Many other application server allow overriding those values.

Comment: It's already stated that you can't modify the .war, so how are you going to add a program to do this?